# CSS absolute positioned button doesnt work in Firefox + fiddle

Tags: html, css

I cant figure out why the red buttons are not displayed properly in firefox. In chrome it looks good.

Here is the fiddle: 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vz89t4d/1/)

That is my chrome:
[image]

That is my firefox:
[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="bilder_bearbeiten col-lg-12">   

            <div class="img-element-del">
                <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg"/>
                <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete6"> Entfernen </a>
            </div>

            <div class="img-element-del">
                <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg"/>
                <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete7"> Entfernen </a>
            </div>

            <div class="img-element-del">
                <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg"/>
                <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete8"> Entfernen </a>
            </div>

            <div class="img-element-del">
                <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg"/>
                <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete9"> Entfernen </a>
            </div>

            <div class="img-element-del">
                <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg"/>
                <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete10"> Entfernen </a>
            </div>
 </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.bilder_bearbeiten img {
    width: 155px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;

}

.img-element-del {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.deletebtn {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 155px;
    position: absolute;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Well I dont know what details to add. I tried to change everything in firefox browser dev tools but could never achieve the same behaviour as in chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/7vz89t4d/2/

```
.img-element-del {
    position: relative; /* this is new */
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.deletebtn {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 155px;

  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 0;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;  /* this is new */
  left: 0;  /* this is new */
}
```

**Short explanation:**
If using `position:absolute;` do also set `position:relative;` to the parent. Then absolute is always from the parent.

This picture might help: [image]

the picture is from [css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) which explains it even a little further.

The above picture in code would look like:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 3px CHOCOLATE;
}

.absolute-one,
.absolute-two,
.absolute-three  {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: CHOCOLATE;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.absolute-one {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.absolute-two {
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
}

.absolute-three  {
  top: 30%;
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="absolute-one">
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  </div>
  <div class="absolute-two">
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 10px;
  </div>
  <div class="absolute-three">
    top: 30%;
    right: -25px;
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle here -> https://jsfiddle.net/7vz89t4d/3/

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.bilder_bearbeiten img {
 width: 155px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  
}

.img-element-del {
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
  
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.deletebtn {
 border-radius: 0;
 width: 155px;
 position: absolute;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bilder_bearbeiten col-lg-12"> 

   <div class="img-element-del">
    <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg"/>
    <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete6"> Entfernen </a>
   </div>

   <div class="img-element-del">
    <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg"/>
    <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete7"> Entfernen </a>
   </div>

   <div class="img-element-del">
    <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg"/>
    <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete8"> Entfernen </a>
   </div>

   <div class="img-element-del">
    <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg"/>
    <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete9"> Entfernen </a>
   </div>

   <div class="img-element-del">
    <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg"/>
    <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete10"> Entfernen </a>
   </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"Left:0;"` and `"bottom:0;"` in your deletebtn css

Answer (score 0):

Here I have craeted a new one. You do not have to use position absolute or something similar.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vz89t4d/6/)

I have just put each "image" and "a" in a div

```
<div class="bilder-row">
<img src="..."/>
<a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete6"> Entfernen </a>
</div>
```

and style:

```
.bilder-row{width:160px;float:left;}
```

this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When styling a page with markup, generally avoid absolute positioning within your layout. Absolutely positioned items make for very brittle layouts which make responsive design very very challenging. Only use it as a last resort. I'd recommend you fully utilize Bootstrap. It's a very powerful tool but is opinionated about your markup. I've refactored your example into something more responsive while taking full advantage of the Bootstrap grid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Here's the full Codepen example: http://codepen.io/toddsby/pen/pRLQem

Viewed on Firefox 51 (macOS)
[image]

## HTML

```
<div class="row gutter-5">
  <div class="img-element-del col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://ghk.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/11/54ff82285cf02-lving-room-green-gold-modern-de.jpg" />
    <div class="deletebtn-container">
      <a class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" href="/user/logged_in/edit_room/22/delete6"> Entfernen </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
/** custom Bootstrap grid gutter **/
.row.gutter-5 {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.gutter-5 > [class*="col-"], .gutter-5 > [class*=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

I've moved the items into a col-3 (12/4) grid. Then styled the image and button to take up 100% of their containers. This allows for a flexible and responsive layout. You can then use Bootstrap breakpoints to target different devices. ie `<div class="img-element-del col-xs-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3">`

Note: This layout would be very simple with Flexbox. As of 2016, Flexbox is supported by all major browsers! You can learn more about Flexbox here: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/understanding-flexbox-everything-you-need-to-know-b4013d4dc9af

Answer (score -1):

Try add `position: relative; to .img-element-del` 
and to .deletebtn add this properties:

```
z-index: 1;
left: 0;
bottom: 10px;
```